# Magento displays incorrect products in category view

Tags: magento, product

When I load a productcollection in list.phtml for the first time (or when I turn of caching completely) the products that are returned are the products which reside in the category which was created last (i.e. the category with the highest id). When cache is turned on, on page-refresh the correct products are shown. After the cache is deleted, the same situation occurs (for the correct products to show I need to refresh the page once when the productlisting is shown).

One extra strange thing; If I call

```
$_product->getCategory()->getName()
```

the correct categoryname is returned, but when

```
$_product->getName()
```

is called, the wrong productname returns... Im at a complete loss here. I have read a similar post elsewhere which stated that when cache is turned on, this problem goes away, but only after the first page-refresh which is highly undesirable.

```
<?php $_coreHelper = $this->helper('core'); ?>

    <?php $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection() ?>

    <?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getName(); ?>
    <?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId(); ?> 


    <?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
    <p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
    <?php else: ?>
    <div class="category-products">

        <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
        <?php $_columnCount = 4; ?>
        <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>

         <?php echo var_dump($_product->getCategory()->getName());  ?>

        <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
            <ul class="products-grid" style="padding-left:0px;">
        <?php endif ?>

        <li style="height:230px;" class="hreview-aggregate hproduct item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">

        <h2 class="item fn product-name">
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_product->getName() ?>"><?php echo substr($this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()), 0, 22).'...' ?></a>
        </h2>

        <div>
            <div>
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image') ?>" class="url product-image"><img class="photo fn" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(100); ?>" width="100" height="100" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" /></a>    
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </div>

        <div>

            <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div><span style="font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;"><?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($newprice,true,false) ?> <?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Ex. BTW') ?></span></div><br />
                    <div><?php echo  $_coreHelper->currency($newtaxprice,true,false) ?> <?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Inc. BTW') ?></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>

            <br />

            <form action="<?=$this->getAddToCartUrl($_product);?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form_<?=$_product->getId();?>" <?if($_product->getOptions()){?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?}?>>
               <?if(!$_product->isGrouped()){?>
                  <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?echo ($this->getMinimalQty($_product)?$this->getMinimalQty($_product):1);?>" style="width:30px;" /> x
               <?}?>
                <button type="button" class="button-order" onclick="this.form.submit()"><span><span><?=$this->__('Bestellen');?></span></span></button>
                <br /><br />
                <span><a href="" style="color:#888;">Zet in verlanglijst</a></span>
            </form> 
            </div>

        </div>

        <div style="clear:both"></div>
                    </li>
                <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
                </ul>
                <?php endif ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <div class="toolbar-bottom">
                <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: is category page rendered with your custom block or with standard one? If with custom check or post getLoadedProductCollection

Answer (score 1):

1. Re-Index all your products in re-indexing page.
2. Clear your cache.
3. Reload your products page.

Comment: It was a problem related to some modifications we made in order to fetch prices from an external ERP solution. The problem has been solved. Thank you for your support !